# Notepad and \n creating crazy caracters

Tags: java

I have a simple program that is calculating prime numbers and writing them to a text file. I tried adding newlines after each one so they would be easier to read. Even though I know notepad does not recognize `\n` I tried opening the file with notepad anyway. What I got was a bunch of Chinese hyroglifics.

here is my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Primes {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("PrimeNumbers.txt", true);
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);

            for (int i = 5; i <= 10000000; i += 2) {
                boolean a = true;

                for (int o = 3; o < ((i / 3) + 1); o += 2) {

                    if (i % o == 0) {
                        a = false;
                        o = i;
                    }

                }
                if (a == true) {
                    bufferedWriter.write(i + "\n");
                }
            }
            bufferedWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

When I open the text file in notepad I get this

```
ਵ਷ㄱㄊਲ਼㜱ㄊਹ㌲㈊ਹㄳ㌊਷ㄴ㐊ਲ਼㜴㔊ਲ਼㤵㘊਱㜶㜊਱㌷㜊ਹ㌸㠊ਹ㜹ㄊ㄰ㄊ㌰ㄊ㜰ㄊ㤰ㄊ㌱ㄊ㜲ㄊㄳㄊ㜳ㄊ㤳ㄊ㤴ㄊㄵㄊ㜵ㄊ㌶ㄊ㜶ㄊ㌷ㄊ㤷ㄊㄸㄊㄹㄊ㌹ㄊ㜹ㄊ㤹㈊ㄱ㈊㌲㈊㜲㈊㤲㈊㌳㈊㤳㈊ㄴ㈊ㄵ㈊㜵㈊㌶㈊㤶㈊ㄷ㈊㜷㈊ㄸ㈊㌸㈊㌹㌊㜰㌊ㄱ㌊㌱㌊㜱㌊ㄳ㌊㜳㌊
```

this just goes on as long as the file is.

Why does this happen?

I also found out that if I add a space before the newline everything is fine.

Comment: Seems like an encoding problem. What encoding are you creating the file in? Try adding a BOM to make it clear. Maybe it's just the very same problem as the [bush hid the facts bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts).

Comment: How do you read the file? Using Windows notepad? What about other tools such as wordpad, notepad++ or your IDE? I cannot reproduce this problem - your code seems fine.

Comment: Which Java version do you use, which compiler? I can't reproduce the case. The generated file has numbers and new lines.

Comment: Note in windows, the separator is `\r\n` (or `System.lineSeparator()`)

Comment: You're in append mode, you know that right?

Answer (score 2):

As rustyx said, `new FileWriter("PrimeNumbers.txt", true)` explicitly uses `append`, which means you are adding to the end of the existing file.

I was able to get garbage, if I use:

```
bufferedWriter.write(i + '\n');
```

(note the `'\n'`, not `"\n"`), which writes an integer (sum of the value plus 10), not a string concatenation. I believe you run similar code before.

So either, delete the file, and try again, or remove the `true` from the `FileWriter` constructor

As a side note, the separator in Windows is `"\r\n"`, or `System.lineSeparator()`.